Python - Pandas matching two json API dumps as dataframes
I'm a network admin working on a small project at work using Cisco's Meraki API wrapper for Python
The end goal is to have a dashboard that displays the amount of authenticated users on a single access point during the set X timeframe. I've been using Pandas to format the json responses and try to work with them but I'm a bit stuck since I never worked with Json, APIs or Pandas.
Dataframe 1 is a list of all access points and their necessary information, looks roughly like this:
name - serial - mac - networkID - model - IP - last updated - Firmware

I then iterate over every serial number in the dataframe to grab the corresponding time data for the serial number
for serial in df['serial']:
 times =[]
times.append(dashboard.wireless.getNetworkWirelessClientCountHistory(networkID,deviceSerial=serial,timespan=3600,resolution=300))
    print(times)

The API Response will be a list with 11 elements each
{'startTs': '2024-12-12T11:05:00Z',
 'endTs': '2024-12-12T11:10:00Z',
 'clientCount': None}

Now I'm at a loss on how to proceed in formatting the data so I can plot it into a simple graph consisting of:
X = timestamp for example 11:05:00
Y = ClientCount for example None
I'm not sure what the easiest way would be, since each API response for the times would need to be matched to the correct Access point so I can display the data for each access point individually.
The dataframe for the times looks roughly like this (per access point)
    startTs                 endTs                   clientCount

0   2024-12-12T10:10:00Z    2024-12-12T10:15:00Z    None

1   2024-12-12T10:15:00Z    2024-12-12T10:20:00Z    None

2   2024-12-12T10:20:00Z    2024-12-12T10:25:00Z    None

3   2024-12-12T10:25:00Z    2024-12-12T10:30:00Z    None

The overall code I have right now:
import meraki
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

API_KEY = 'API_KEY_HERE'

dashboard = meraki.DashboardAPI(API_KEY)

org_id = 'ORG_ID_HERE'
Network_ID = 'MERAKI_NETWORK_ID_HERE'
client_id = ''

#get all devices
response = dashboard.organizations.getOrganizationDevices(
     org_id, total_pages='all', networkIds= NETWORK_ID_HERE
)

#filter for APs
response = list(filter(lambda x: x['productType'] == "wireless",response))
df = pd.DataFrame(response)
#drop columns
df = df.drop(['details','url','tags','notes','lng','lat','address','productType'],axis=1)

for serial in df['serial']:
    times = []

times.append(dashboard.wireless.getNetworkWirelessClientCountHistory(NETWORK_ID_HERE,deviceSerial=serial,timespan=3600,resolution=300))

Not sure how to fix the formatting on that last line but you get the general idea hopefully, I've been watching youtube videos on pandas as a library but I'm yet to figure out how I need to solve this. Any pointer is appreciated!

Your for serial in df['serial']: loop is not doing what you hope at least as far as how we see the code formatted.

I know the formatting on that last line is off, can't figure out how to get it back where it needs to be in the text editor but it does what I want it to do, the table with the times and authentication numbers is working, I just need to map the two tables together and be able to access the time, client count and Serial on their own and map it to a graph

Do you want one row in the output per row returned by getNetworkWirelessClientCountHistory with the repeated information from the "parent" getOrganizationDevices row?

@JonSG yes something like that, in an ideal scenario I'd like the dashboard to have a selection of Access points which I can easily do with the first Dataframe and then have a selection of possible time frames (1 days, 7 days, 30 days) but for that I'd have to map the time stamps with the authentication counts to the correct Access point
Is it possible to have nested dataframes? For example Dataframe 1 could look something like this:
name - serial - mac - networkID - model - IP - last updated - Firmware - Times
And in the times column it would be
Time stamp - authentication count
